# Angular filter в разных контроллерах

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-controller

Есть контроллер хедера в котором находится поиск, и есть контроллер статей. Подскажите решение для организации фильтрации из инпута поиска.

Вариант с `ng-model` на инпуте и `| filter:` в `ng-repeat` не работает. Спасибо

Comment: вариант с ng-model на инпуте и | filter: в ng-repeat вполне себе работает. Добавь пример своего кода, чтобы можно было точнее сказать как его переделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда делал что-то подобное, при изменении формы поиска в шапке я добавлял параметр в урл 
`?search=[строка поиска]`

В контроллере статей проверял значение параметра search при первой загрузке и подписывался на изменения

```
$rootScope.$on( "$locationChangeSuccess", function(event, next, current) {
   // get articles
})
```

Тем самым, у вас будет прямая ссылка на поисковый запрос, это может быть удобно.